# Reading an audiostream in python

Tags: python, audio, stream, inputstream

Amazingly, in bash, you can do

```
$ curl http://mp3.streampower.be/radio1-high.mp3 > test.mp3
```

with an audiostream and then ^C out, and you will have a working mp3 file, leading me to believe I could have this automated in python, but I can't find how.

If i just do

```
file('python.mp3', 'w').write(urllib2.urlopen("http://mp3.streampower.be/radio1-high.mp3").read())
```

it doesn't even read the stream.

Is there something like BufferedInputReader from java in python or can anyone give me some pointers as to how I would go about doing this? Reading an audiostream and getting it to stop reading after a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd probably do better to save the file-like object from `urllib2.urlopen()` and then use its `read` method in a loop with a size parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

f=file('python.mp3', 'w')

url=urllib2.urlopen("http://mp3.streampower.be/radio1-high.mp3")

while True:
    f.write(url.read(1024))
```

Your code was calling `read` without a size parameter -- which tries to read the whole thing. It's a stream, so that will be a while. If the stream ever closes, *then* your call to `write` could proceed, and you'd go from no file to a huge file in no time.

My sample code here will build you an mp3 file nice and slow. You may need to tweak the `1024` if the streams are sending much faster than typical mp3 bitrates, but this should be fine. (A 128kbps stream would involve 16 system calls per second to `write(2)`, which shouldn't be any stress at all. But at 10mbit speeds or higher, it'd hurt, and you should use a larger `read` size.)

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case the mp3 is not playing well, having a lot of small cuts in it. Any idea that could help improving ? The stream is playing well from Firefox or VLC

Comment: @Stéphane, try with larger block sizes, `10240` or more?

Comment: Actually that does the trick ... and it's now working with 1024 as well. Don't understand why, but thanks :-)